# Decoding Input Data

Tags: web3.py

I'm trying to decode the input data in a transaction... I've been stuck on this for a while, as I'm really new to using this api.
I have written the below example, but I'm getting stuck when loading the ABI to contract. Can someone help me understand the issue here?

```
import urllib.request, json 
from web3 import Web3

provider = Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
w3 = Web3(provider)

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xC12D1c73eE7DC3615BA4e37E4ABFdbDDFA38907E ") as url:
    ABI = json.loads(url.read())

contract = w3.eth.contract(address='0xC12D1c73eE7DC3615BA4e37E4ABFdbDDFA38907E',abi=ABI)

transaction = w3.eth.getTransaction("0xf9d681d1e759dd56a8a110aca39b6c619234ad609afb021ddeb3f0e8a1c59fc1")
contract.decode_function_input(transaction.input)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Could not format value {'status': '1', ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue here is that the HTTP request returns a dict containing 3 keys, one of which holds the value:

```
{"status":"0", "message":"NOTOK", "result":"Maximum rate limit reached"}
```

There are two minor issues:

1. If the "status" key in the response holds the value "0", it indicates that you have exceeded your request limit of 1 request per second (only applicable if you did not supply an API key). Additional informations [here](https://info.etherscan.com/api-return-errors/).
2. It's a good practice to also handle HTTP response codes

Fixed code:

```
import urllib.request, json
from time import sleep
from web3 import Web3

provider = Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
w3 = Web3(provider)
txid = '0xf9d681d1e759dd56a8a110aca39b6c619234ad609afb021ddeb3f0e8a1c59fc1'
address = '0xC12D1c73eE7DC3615BA4e37E4ABFdbDDFA38907E'
requrl = 'http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=' + address

while True:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(requrl) as url:
        if url.code != 200:
            # TODO: Error handling
            raise NotImplementedError('I don\'t know how to handle HTTP code {} :('.format(url.code))
        else:
            result = json.loads(url.read())

            if result['status'] == '1':
                abi = json.loads(result['result'])
                break

            # In this scenario status is only not 1 if you used your 1 req/sec. (25 Feb. 2020)
            sleep(1)

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
transaction = w3.eth.getTransaction(txid)
contract.decode_function_input(transaction.input)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback... I'll work on all your suggestions... It worked... can't believe it, it's amazing... hopefully this post will help others decode transactions with python... since I couldn't find fully usable code out there...

Comment: @AceCal Glad I could help. I also hope that your example can help others. Have a good time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first to verify your smart contract [here](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract), then you need also to provide your API KEY

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xC12D1c73eE7DC3615BA4e37E4ABFdbDDFA38907E&apikey=**YOUR_API_KEY_HERE**

Comment: thanks for your reply... Other than the missing API key, the ABI format needs to be in a string inside a list kind of format as well, while with the method above it's imported directly as a python dict